# Python: how to grab a substrings when the indices are dynamic

Tags: python, string, substring

I am working with many lines in a file, in which I want to retrieve a certain element which may be of varying length, and is not flanked consistently by the same characters.

Here's an example. I want to retrieve the item that starts with "OOO_" on each line:

```
blah blah OOO_128934( blah blah
blah bloop OOO_231 bloop bloop
beep OOO_421398234beep beep
```

Solutions with/without using the re module are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then maybe:

```
text = """
blah blah OOO_128934( blah blah
blah bloop OOO_231 bloop bloop
beep OOO_421398234beep beep
"""

import re

print re.findall(r'OOO_\d+', text) 
>>> ['OOO_128934', 'OOO_231', 'OOO_421398234']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "blah bloop OOO_231 bloop bloop"
>>> next(x for x in s.split() if x.startswith("OOO_"))
'OOO_231'
```

Comment: Good suggestion. But I have a hunch (s)he wants "OOO_128934" for the first one and "OOO_421398234" for the last one.